# Need helps understanding Relativistic mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor, inertial-frames

Could anyone explain the equation for total energy and relativistic momentum, why do they have a Lorentz factor in them? I also understand that these equations are derived such that they keep the laws of physics the same in all inertial frames of reference, but how does it do that?